# How can I find out if a file exists from an fs.Stats object?

Tags: linux, node.js, filesystems, stat

I mean, that's basically it.  The nodejs docs state that `exists` is an anachonism, but I can't see how `stat` replaces it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fs.stat()` method doesn't actually replace `fs.exists()`, but you can find out if a file exists through an error code from other functions. You would directly use `fs.stat()` on a file, regardless of if the file existed or not. The same thing applies to `fs.open()`, `fs.readFile()`, etc.

```
fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) {
  // if err is ENOENT
});
```

The documentation suggests doing this because it removes the possibility of a race condition happening between a `fs.exists()` call and a actual file operation, where the file could be deleted in the time between asynchronous functions.

---

Here's an example of directly checking if a file exists, and if so, reading it. If a file doesn't exists, an `err` object's `code` property will contain the string `ENOENT`.

```
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', function(err, data) {
  if (err.code == 'ENOENT') {
    // the file doesn't exist
  }

  // the file exists if there are no other errors
});
```

Comment: I don't understand this. Can you show an actual syntactically valid boolean expression denoting the file's existence status instead of just a comment? Thanks.

Comment: But what if I don't care if it's a file or a directory, or if a race condition occurs, just if it exists?

Comment: Then feel free to use `fs.exists()`.